# Intellij @Autowired. No matching spring beans found

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

> JAVA 1.7
>   Spring 4.3.7
>   IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)
>   Build #IU-173.4548.28, built on January 30, 2018
>   JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b11 x86_64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
>   Mac OS X 10.13.3

why not found? the code has no problem and the test was successful.

But I'm concerned about the error mark.

useDefaultFilters false = not found.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "org.fxb.module",
    useDefaultFilters = false,
    includeFilters = {
        @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, classes = { Aspect.class, Mapper.class }),
    }
)
public class ModuleConfiguration {
  @Autowired
  private ModuleContextAOP moduleContextAOP;
```

[image]

useDefaultFilters = true = found.

[image]

AOP code

```
package org.fxb.module.aop;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ModuleContextAOP {
```

[image]

I think it's a code with no problems. I do not understand why IntelliJ seems to be an error.

Comment: There is no way how anyone can help you if we get nothing but your java version and tiny blurry snippets of screenshots. Please re-read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Sorry I can speak a little English. But what more should I add?

Comment: You should strive for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that significantly increases the chances to get a good answer. As mentioned in the 'How to Ask' linked above, you should also avoid posting images of code instead of actual code, because nobody wants to re-type pieces of code manually.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I uploaded an image to show errors for intellij.

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely better to have at least some code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187757

includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, **classes = Component.class**)

to

includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, **value = Component.class**)

Resolved.

Thank...

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't able to autowire the component because the class ModuleConfiguration where you are autowiring ModuleContextAOP isn't a component. Try annotating ModuleConfiguration with component and it should work. Usually @Configuration is used for defining beans but you are trying to autowire them.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `ModuleConfiguration` **is not a Spring bean class** hence dependencies on it cannot be autowired. You need to either put the bean entry for the class inside XML file (where you declare other spring beans) or annotate it with `@component`.

`@Component` Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.

Or you can use `@Configuration` to scan all the spring bean into a class
`@Configuration` is the heart of the Java-based configuration mechanism that was introduced in Spring 3. It provides an alternative to the XML-based configuration.

So the 2 following snippets are identical:

```
<beans ...>
    <context:component-scan base-package="my.base.package"/>
    ... other configuration ...
</beans>
```

and:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my.base.package")
public class RootConfig {
    ... other configuration ...
}
```

In both cases, Spring will scan in my.base.package and below for classes annotated with `@Component` or one of the other annotations that are meta-annotated with `@Component` such as `@Service`.